# Using Acts-As-Taggable on Multiple Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Quick question.

I'm trying to use the Acts-As-Taggable gem to search for multiple tags at the same time. The trick is, I want to search for any posts containing at least one of the tags. I've partially figured it out.

If in my songs controller I put

```
if params[:tag]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(["Hip-Hop-3, Hip-Hop-5"], :any => true)
elsif...
```

It will find all posts containing one or more of the tags.

The problem is, when I want to move these parameters into a ERB link_to

Here is my controller:

```
if params[:tag]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:tag], :any => true).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 36)
elsif
```

Here is my link_to

```
<%= link_to "House", tag_path(["Hip-Hop-5","Hip-Hop-3"]) %>
```

In this situation the URL is the same, http://localhost:3000/tags/Hip-Hop-5/Hip-Hop-3, but it doesn't show any of the posts like the previous method did.

Am I doing something wrong with the parameter?

OR

Is there a way I can have the tagged_with method search for tags containing certain characters. So find tags that contain the word "Hip-Hop" in it? Thank you!

Thank you,

Matt

Comment: That url makes my eyes hurt. Wouldn't something like http://localhost:3000/songs&style=house be better? Then you can map params["style"=>"house"] in the controller (or model, depending on design) to get 'Hip-Hop-5' and 'Hip-Hop-3'.

Comment: Hey jvillian, i totally agree that the tags are really messy. I'm just trying to get this to work first then I'll fix that. Good suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the url as follows:

`<%= link_to "House", tag_path(tag: ["Hip-Hop-5","Hip-Hop-3"]) %>`

I believe that the controller won't be able to find params[:tag] as per your link because it is not passed as hash to the method tag_path, using `tag: params[:tag]` should ensure correct assignment of the params[:tag] to the parameters you were passing.

Comment: Hey Thresh, just tried this. Still no luck. Any other suggestions

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your full controller code, also include the model of the songs. maybe there is something I am missing. Also I need to know what is the exact output that you get. Do you have an errors, or the page renders normally with out any errors, and when you inspect @songs inside the if condition, what its value is?